# pdf download is not working for anchor tag

Tags: c#, html

Hi following is my html to download pdf

```
  <a href="../media/external/NewFile.pdf" class="color-green" style="margin-right: 35px;" download>
                     Notice
                </a>
```

But when I tried to download pdf it is downloading Login.html instead of NewFile.pdf. NewFile.pdf is physically present in the external folder also if I added any JPG file in external folder and change path /NewFile.jpg then it is downloading .jpg file but unable to do .pdf please suggest.

Comment: `target="_blank"` can you try to add this attribute. let see what will happen.

Comment: What does it do? Do you get a 404 error? Is your relative path correct? As in, on the page you're wanting to download, does the PDF exist a folder back and then in to `/media/external/`

Comment: already tried target="_blank" its not working

Comment: My relative path is correct I am not getting 404 either. login page is downloading instead of NewFile.pdf

Comment: Is this a web application with authentication of some sorts? Looks like path of your file requires authentication.

Comment: It's weird that it wants to download a page that isn't referenced anywhere. are you on the login page when this happens? Also, what browser are you using (Version too)

Comment: .jpg files from the same folder is accessible and getting downloaded. the problem is for only .pdf extension

Comment: Using Chrome latest version

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
     <a href="./media/external/testtttt.pdf" class="color-green" style="margin-right: 35px;" download="test.pdf" target="_blank">
                 Notice
            </a>
```

Here, media folder is in location as same as "index.html" file. Means I made path for media folder same as like index.html file. Also i used download attribute to rename and download the file.

Comment: Well this won't download the file. It will just open it in a new window.